# Async worker on gunicorn seems blocking

Tags: flask, gunicorn, gevent

I am using a Flask app with the gunicorn server and the gevent worker class, which according to [the gunicorn documentation](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html) is an asynchronous worker. However, when I launch gunicorn with a single worker and try to make a long request (I added `sleep(10)` in the route function, but in reality this also happens when processing large uploads), I can't make any request until the previous one is finished. It behaves as is it is a synchronous worker, one request at a time.

Is this the normal behavior? Am I missing something about synchronous vs asynchronous workers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't monkey-patch `sleep` (or use `gevent`'s [non-blocking version of `sleep`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.sleep)) then a worker that blocks *blocks the entire event loop*.

Either call [`gevent.monkey.patch_all`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_all) (or more specifically [`gevent.monkey.patch_time`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html#gevent.monkey.patch_time)) *or* replace your call to `time.sleep` with [`gevent.sleep`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.html#gevent.sleep)