# How to run Flask with Gunicorn in multithreaded mode

Tags: python, flask, machine-learning, gunicorn

I have web application written in Flask. As suggested by everyone, I can't use Flask in production. So I thought of **Gunicorn with Flask**.

In Flask application I am loading some Machine Learning models. These are of size 8GB collectively. Concurrency of my web application can go upto **1000 requests**. And the RAM of machine is 15GB.
So what is the best way to run this application?

Comment: Seeing this is quite old, but could you tell us please what did you go with in the end? Having the same situation currently..

Comment: got solution? @neel

Answer (score 73):

You can start your app with multiple workers or async workers with Gunicorn.

Flask server.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Gunicorn with gevent async worker

```
gunicorn server:app -k gevent --worker-connections 1000
```

Gunicorn 1 worker 12 threads:

```
gunicorn server:app -w 1 --threads 12
```

Gunicorn with 4 workers (multiprocessing):

```
gunicorn server:app -w 4
```

More information on Flask concurrency in this post: [How many concurrent requests does a single Flask process receive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938360/how-many-concurrent-requests-does-a-single-flask-process-receive).

Comment: With multiple workers it is throwing out of memory exception as size of models is large. I think with each worker it will load all models in different memory space

Comment: You need to use async worker like gevent to allow concurrency with one worker: `gunicorn -k gevent --worker-connections 1000`.

Comment: You can also add `--threads` to run each worker with the specified number of threads. See Edit.

Comment: Which worker type should I use if my api call is taking around 1sec?

Comment: I'll go with gevent and monkey patch your app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527351/async-worker-on-gunicorn-seems-blocking. You can also have a look to celery to run background tasks.

Comment: @neel did you got any solution, I've same problem

Answer (score 15):

The best thing to do is to use pre-fork mode ([preload_app=True](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#preload-app)). This will initialize your code in a "master" process and then simply fork off worker processes to handle requests. If you are running on linux and assuming your model is read-only, the OS is smart enough to reuse the physical memory amongst all the processes.

Comment: The problem I found with this is that if you are running databases, they will complain that the database instance shouldn't be forked. In my case, MongoClient from pyMongo `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py:164: UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking.`

Comment: yes, in those cases you need to be sure to initialize those connections post fork. after that it should be fine.

Comment: I confirm, such memory reuse in Linux systems (such as our Ubuntu containers), is evident also for multiple `optuna` scripts (training rather memory-intensive ML models) executed in parallel using multiprocessing.