# Connecting to Flask server from different devices on network results in timeout

Tags: python, flask, configuration, devserver

I'm currently learning Flask and I decided to try to connect to a very simple server from other devices on my network. I followed the advice given at 
[Flask - configure dev server to be visible across the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/flask-configure-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network/35146471#35146471) and changed

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

However, it does not work correctly.

I have a Flask server setup as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hey there'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I start the server this is the output:

```
Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

The server works fine when I connect via the localhost however, I always get a timeout when I try to connect from another device on the same network using:

```
http://<my_ip_address>:5000
```

I have tried connecting to the server (which is running on my Macbook Air) from both my Windows 7 Desktop and my iPhone, with both of them receiving timeouts.

Any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you have to configure your firewall or enable [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) on your router...

Comment: Are you connecting to the local network IP? i.e. 192.168... 172... 10...??? I can see you have omitted it from the question makes me think you are using external IP of the router.

Comment: I have configured my firewall on my Mac to allow connections to port 5000.  I have not tried port forwarding yet.   I am connecting using http://192.168.x.x      using the IP next to inet when I run ifconfig

Comment: is there anything else running on that port? Try changing the port by setting `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8082)`

Comment: my workaround was `app.run(host='my_ip_addr',port=5000)`

Comment: The development server can only [handle one client at a time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14815932/2800058).

Answer (score 2):

To [handle requests concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876721/handle-flask-requests-concurrently-with-threaded-true) you can run Flask with:

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

By default Flask runs with one thread so subsequent requests are blocked until the thread becomes available. In production, you'll want a WSGI container like Gunicorn to [manage workers and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35839360/6085135).