# Flask : Server not responding on internal API access

Tags: python, rest, api, flask

I was trying develop web application using flask, below is my code,

```
from sample import APIAccessor
#API
@app.route('/test/triggerSecCall',methods=['GET'])
def triggerMain():
    resp = APIAccessor().trigger2()
    return Response(json.dumps(resp), mimetype='application/json') 

@app.route('/test/seccall',methods=['GET'])
def triggerSub():
    resp = {'data':'called second method'}
    return Response(json.dumps(resp), mimetype='application/json')
```

And my trigger method contains the following code,

```
def trigger2(self):
      url = 'http:/127.0.0.1:5000/test/seccall' 
      response = requests.get(url) 
      response.raise_for_status()
      responseJson = response.json()
      if self.track:
          print 'Response:::%s' %str(responseJson)
      return responseJson
```

When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/seccall`, I get the expected output. When I hit `/test/triggerSecCall`, the server stop responding. The request waits forever. 
At this stage, I am not able to access any apis from anyother REST clients. When I force stop the server(Ctrl+C) I am getting response in the `second` REST client.

Why flask is not able to serve to internal service call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using the single threaded development server and not a WSGI setup for production.

Since the server has only one thread is can handle one request at a time. The first request will be executed, resulting in the `requests.get(...)` which will open a second request that can not be handled until the first request is complete, a dead lock.

The best solution would be to just call `triggerSub()` to get the result instead of using an HTTP request.

Comment: Yes! I typing out the same thing. More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876721/handle-flask-requests-concurrently-with-threaded-true

Comment: Thank you Klaus and MacMaclirish. I think making my application to run in multiple thread will solve my problem. And it's just a simple application which will be used by few people.

Comment: Well, it would be a solution to run the server multi-threaded, but that would just mask the underlying problem. If you web app does not run in one thread there is something wrong with it. Also multiple thread will complicate debugging.

Comment: @MacMcIrish, The link was so useful. I will defiantly consider all the topic discussed in that thread.

Comment: If you use it for anything else then development use a WSGI setup. Guncorn can serve it simply.

Comment: Sure Klaus, I will use WSGI in later phase. For now I added `app.run(host= '0.0.0.0',threaded=True)` and it solved my problem.