# Multiprocessing causes Python to crash and gives an error may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, macos

I am relatively new to Python and trying to implement a Multiprocessing module for my for loop.

I have an array of Image url's stored in img_urls which I need to download and apply some Google vision.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    img_urls = [ALL_MY_Image_URLS]
    runAll(img_urls)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This is my runAll() method

```
def runAll(img_urls):
    num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    print("Image URLS  {}",len(img_urls))
    if len(img_urls) > 2:
        numberOfImages = 0
    else:
        numberOfImages = 1

    start_timeProcess = time.time()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(annotate,img_urls)
    end_timeProcess = time.time()
    print('\n Time to complete ', end_timeProcess-start_timeProcess)

    print(full_matching_pages)


def annotate(img_path):
    file =  requests.get(img_path).content
    print("file is",file)
    """Returns web annotations given the path to an image."""
    print('Process Working under ',os.getpid())
    image = types.Image(content=file)
    web_detection = vision_client.web_detection(image=image).web_detection
    report(web_detection)
```

I am getting this as the warning when I run it and python crashes

```
objc[67570]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67570]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
objc[67567]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67567]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
objc[67568]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67568]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
objc[67569]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67569]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
objc[67571]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67571]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
objc[67572]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[67572]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Comment: Are you on OSX? Then perhaps [this bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32499) gives you some hints.

Comment: Oh Yeah I am on OSX, thank you for pointing me to the link.

Comment: Still no luck tried setting the `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` as mentioned, still get the same error. @IonicSolutions

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no specific knowledge on this topic. All I can do is use Google to find related issues, e.g. [this possible workaround](https://bugs.python.org/issue30385#msg293958).

Comment: This is due to [Apple changing macOS `fork()` behavior since High Sierra](https://blog.phusion.nl/2017/10/13/why-ruby-app-servers-break-on-macos-high-sierra-and-what-can-be-done-about-it/).  The `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=yes` variable turns off the immediate crash behavior that their newer ObjectiveC framework usually enforces now by default.  This can affect any language that is doing multithreading / multiprocessing using `fork()` on macOS `>= 10.13`, especially when "native extensions" / C code extensions are used.

Comment: There are also some [Python specific issues](https://codewithoutrules.com/2017/08/16/concurrency-python/) w.r.t. [multithreading & multiprocessing](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/) that you might want to be aware of.  It's common to run into deadlock and performance issues with Python threads due to the way Python is designed, specifically the ["GIL" / Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: [Another good discussion](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2017/6/5/Objective-C_and_fork_in_macOS_1013.html) of the issue, [thanks to Reddit user "`snatchery`"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/72qxjv/kernelfork_broken_in_macos_1013_high_sierra_puma/dnks820/)

Comment: Also [a summary thanks to Reddit user "`Nwallins`"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/72qxjv/kernelfork_broken_in_macos_1013_high_sierra_puma/dnl8unj/)

Answer (score 410, accepted):

This error occurs because of added security to restrict multithreading in macOS High Sierra and later versions of macOS.  I know this answer is a bit late, but I solved the problem using the following method:

Set an environment variable `.bash_profile` (or `.zshrc` for recent macOS) to allow multithreading applications or scripts under the new macOS High Sierra security rules.

Open a terminal:

```
$ nano .bash_profile
```

Add the following line to the end of the file:

```
OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

Save, exit, close terminal and re-open the terminal.  Check to see that the environment variable is now set:

```
$ env
```

You will see output similar to:

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/pn/vasdlj3ojO#OOas4dasdffJq/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.E7qLFJDSo/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=404
TERM_SESSION_ID=NONE
OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

You should now be able to run your Python script with multithreading.

Comment: This actually solved it for me. I wanted to iterate a large pandas dataframe across multiple threads, and ran into the same issue described by the op. This answer solved the issue for me. Only difference is that I set that env variable with the script I ran: `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES python my-script.py`

Comment: Thanks so much! For those interested, this worked for me on macOS Mojave.

Comment: This solved my issue, but my script was using multi-processing

Comment: It worked on my machine with macOS Mojave, but then my pytest tests don't run in parallel anymore. Before, it was crashing, but at least, it was fast...

Comment: This environment variable solved my issue of running ansible locally on my mac (catalina)

Comment: This worked for me on catalina after passing the env var to my virtual env (using tox) `passenv =
    OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY`

Comment: works for me, running on Catalina. Note that in Catalina (for my case at least), my profile was in `~/.zprofile` and not `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This also worked for me on MacOS Catalina by editing ~/.zshrc :)

Comment: It not worked on my machine, macOS 11.1, python3.8

Comment: It doesn't work on my Ubuntu machine with python3.8

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS Big Sur

Comment: I had to add 'export' in front of: OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES

Comment: Not works on python3.9 & MacOS Venture

Answer (score 45):

Running MAC and z-shell and in my .zshrc-file I had to add:

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

and then in the command line:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Then it worked

Comment: You could also run the `export` command on the terminal you are working on, or in set it as an environment variable in case you use an IDE (ex pyCharm). On this case you will use this variable for specific projects only, not for every python tool running on your machine.

Answer (score 25):

the other answers are telling you to set `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`, but don't do this! you're just putting sticky tape on the warning light. You may need this on a case by case basis for some legacy software but certainly do not set this in your `.bash_profile`!

this is fixed in https://bugs.python.org/issue33725 (python3.8+) but it's best practice to use

```
with multiprocessing.get_context("spawn").Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(annotate,img_urls)
```

Comment: This is certainly a valid answer but readers should be aware that a lot of mulitprocessing code based on "fork" mode will not work with "spawn". "spawn" requires the code to be designed from the start to work this way. You need to be careful about shared objects, and you don't have the memory-state of the parent. Fork gives copy-on-write access to all variables which is really useful!

Answer (score 8):

The `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY = YES` solution didn't work for me.  Another potential solution is setting `no_proxy = *` in your script environment [as described here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74570#issuecomment-1093748531).

Besides the causes covered by others, this error message can also be networking related. My script has a tcp server.  I don't even use a pool, just `os.fork` and `multiprocessing.Queue` for message passing.  The forks worked fine until I added the queue.

Setting no_proxy by itself fixed it in my case.  If your script has networking components, try this fix - perhaps in combination with `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY`.

Comment: I had one error before I added `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`, then a different one, and then it worked after I added `no_proxy=*`. So I think I needed both.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that works for me without `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY` flag in the environment involves initializing the `multiprocessing.Pool` class right after the `main()` program starts.

This is most likely not the fastest solution possible and I am not sure if it works in all situations, however, pre-heating the worker processes early enough before my programs starts does not result in any `... may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called` errors and I do get a significant performance boost compared to what I get with non-parallelized code.

I have created a convenience class `Parallelizer` which I am starting very early and then using throughout the lifecycle of my program. The full version can be found [here](https://github.com/strictdoc-project/strictdoc/blob/e66f52f498db82d804137856c576a7357c1370fa/strictdoc/helpers/parallelizer.py).

```
# entry point to my program
def main():
    parallelizer = Parallelizer()
    ...
```

Then whenever you want to have parallelization:

```
# this function is parallelized. it is run by each child process.
def processing_function(input):
    ...
    return output

...
inputs = [...]
results = parallelizer.map(
    inputs,
    processing_function
)
```

And the parallelizer class:

```
class Parallelizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.output_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
                                         Parallelizer._run,
                                         (self.input_queue, self.output_queue,))

    def map(self, contents, processing_func):
        size = 0
        for content in contents:
            self.input_queue.put((content, processing_func))
            size += 1
        results = []
        while size > 0:
            result = self.output_queue.get(block=True)
            results.append(result)
            size -= 1
        return results

    @staticmethod
    def _run(input_queue, output_queue):
        while True:
            content, processing_func = input_queue.get(block=True)
            result = processing_func(content)
            output_queue.put(result)
```

One caveat: the parallelized code might be difficult to debug so I have also prepared a non-parallelizing version of my class which I enable when something goes wrong in the child processes:

```
class NullParallelizer:
    @staticmethod
    def map(contents, processing_func):
        results = []
        for content in contents:
            results.append(processing_func(content))
        return results
```