# pip3 crashes on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew

I've just upgraded to macOS Catalina, I've used `brew install dpkg`, and homebrew decided it was time to run `brew cleanup`.

After running it, I've not been able to run `pip3` anymore.

Tried running `brew doctor` and `brew reinstall python3`, but none helped.

Running pip3 outputs this:

`[1]    26346 abort      pip3`

Comment: your cross post on Apple-SE: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372136/pip3-abort-signal-on-startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `brew uninstall python3` does not really uninstalls it, had to remove `/usr/local/lib/python3` to really remove the installation, and then reinstall python using `brew install python3`

Answer (score 6):

I meet the same problem, and i found the solution for this problem, you can check this comment in [github](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/44996#issuecomment-540674866), it's works for me.

> I found something that may be helpful!
>   The `asn1crypto` python package imports libcrypto. I removed this package from my site packages `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and now pip3 works

Answer (score 2):

The [solution to libcrypto complaining about using unversioned dylib](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119429) from [r.xuan](https://forums.developer.apple.com/people/r.xuan) that [Marcos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10080122/marcos) linked to seems like the best workaround for now. The steps in a bit more fool-proof fashion can be found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58383291/9788634).