# macOS Catalina: Python Quit unexpectedly error

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

I just upgraded to macOS Catalina from Mojave on my Macbook and tried to run a python3 script from terminal as follows: python3 scriptname.py
I get no response in the terminal and then error comes up : Python Quit unexpectedly with the following report: Please help me solve this or how do i downgrade to mojave as i need this to work

```
Process:               Python [2726]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.4 (3.7.4)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [2723]
Responsible:           Terminal [1574]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-01-23 23:24:33.722 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.2 (19C57)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        xxxx


Time Awake Since Boot: 1700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000110
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2726]

VM Regions Near 0x110:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000109159000-000000010915a000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Application Specific Information:
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec
Invalid dylib load. Clients should not load the unversioned libcrypto dylib as it does not have a stable ABI.

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff65580ce6 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff65642185 _pthread_cond_wait + 701
2   org.python.python               0x0000000109281cfd PyThread_acquire_lock_timed + 413
3   org.python.python               0x00000001092cb20f acquire_timed + 111
4   org.python.python               0x00000001092cb320 lock_PyThread_acquire_lock + 48
5   org.python.python               0x00000001091841dd _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 685
6   org.python.python               0x0000000109189d42 _PyMethodDescr_FastCallKeywords + 82
7   org.python.python               0x00000001092428ec call_function + 780
8   org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
9   org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
10  org.python.python               0x00000001091835a1 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
11  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
12  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
13  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
14  org.python.python               0x00000001091835a1 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
15  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
16  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
17  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
18  org.python.python               0x0000000109183004 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 148
19  org.python.python               0x000000010923fb9e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25966
20  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
21  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
22  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
23  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
24  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
25  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
26  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
27  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
28  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
29  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
30  org.python.python               0x0000000109183004 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 148
31  org.python.python               0x00000001091844bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
32  org.python.python               0x00000001091d2d61 slot_tp_init + 145
33  org.python.python               0x00000001091ce749 type_call + 297
34  org.python.python               0x00000001091833f1 _PyObject_FastCallKeywords + 433
35  org.python.python               0x0000000109242784 call_function + 420
36  org.python.python               0x000000010923f92e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25342
37  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
38  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
39  org.python.python               0x000000010923f88d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25181
40  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
41  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
42  org.python.python               0x000000010923f88d _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25181
43  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
44  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
45  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
46  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
47  org.python.python               0x0000000109239554 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
48  org.python.python               0x0000000109276c31 PyRun_FileExFlags + 209
49  org.python.python               0x00000001092764aa PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 890
50  org.python.python               0x0000000109295903 pymain_main + 6915
51  org.python.python               0x0000000109295e6a _Py_UnixMain + 58
52  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6543d7fd start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff653f4a29 dispatch_apply_f + 749
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd9598f __104-[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:]_block_invoke.119 + 97
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd9591d CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_AND_USER_CFPREFSDS + 74
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd957b7 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:] + 172
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd942a3 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_generationCountFromListOfSources:count:] + 215
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd93fe0 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_getDictionary:] + 360
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd93c04 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_copyValueForKey:] + 152
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd93b4c -[CFPrefsSource copyValueForKey:] + 47
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd93b0a __76-[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:]_block_invoke + 32
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd8ba1c __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 381
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd8b51f -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 364
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd8b2ae -[_CFXPreferences copyAppValueForKey:identifier:container:configurationURL:] + 145
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2dd8b1e3 _CFPreferencesCopyAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 101
13  com.apple.SystemConfiguration   0x00007fff3b55901c SCDynamicStoreCopyProxiesWithOptions + 155
14  _scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so  0x000000010a5fc880 get_proxy_settings + 32
15  org.python.python               0x0000000109184225 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 757
16  org.python.python               0x00000001091835da _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 42
17  org.python.python               0x00000001092428b4 call_function + 724
18  org.python.python               0x000000010923f92e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25342
19  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
20  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
21  org.python.python               0x000000010923f92e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25342
22  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
23  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
24  org.python.python               0x000000010923f92e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25342
25  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
26  org.python.python               0x00000001091835a1 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
27  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
28  org.python.python               0x000000010923f9d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25508
29  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
30  org.python.python               0x00000001091835a1 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
31  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
32  org.python.python               0x000000010923f9d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25508
33  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
34  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
35  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
36  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
37  org.python.python               0x000000010918317b _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 523
38  org.python.python               0x00000001091844bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
39  org.python.python               0x0000000109183707 PyObject_Call + 135
40  org.python.python               0x000000010923fb9e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25966
41  org.python.python               0x0000000109243413 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2467
42  org.python.python               0x00000001091835a1 _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 257
43  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
44  org.python.python               0x000000010923f9d4 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25508
45  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
46  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
47  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
48  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
49  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
50  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
51  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
52  org.python.python               0x00000001092428c2 call_function + 738
53  org.python.python               0x000000010923f873 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25155
54  org.python.python               0x0000000109183a10 function_code_fastcall + 128
55  org.python.python               0x0000000109183004 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 148
56  org.python.python               0x00000001091844bf _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 143
57  org.python.python               0x0000000109183707 PyObject_Call + 135
58  org.python.python               0x00000001092cab77 t_bootstrap + 71
59  org.python.python               0x0000000109281939 pythread_wrapper + 25
60  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff65641e65 _pthread_start + 148
61  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6563d83b thread_start + 15

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010ac01040  rbx: 0x0000000000000100  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x00007fff653f439c  rsi: 0x00007fff8f281a00  rbp: 0x0000700003b579f0  rsp: 0x0000700003b57960
   r8: 0x000000010ac01040   r9: 0x000000010ac00080  r10: 0x000000010ac00000  r11: 0x000000010ac00080
  r12: 0x0000000000000001  r13: 0x000000010ac01040  r14: 0x00000000100008ff  r15: 0x000000010ac01000
  rip: 0x00007fff653f4a29  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000010b87f020

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000131
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x109159000 -        0x109159fff +org.python.python (3.7.4 - 3.7.4) <4B030EC4-815E-34B7-90E7-D0720C31E072> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x109162000 -        0x10933bfff +org.python.python (3.7.4, [c] 2001-2019 Python Software Foundation. - 3.7.4) <AC1AEBEB-FF5A-32AD-BAE0-C6A0BCA86B84> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python
       0x109779000 -        0x10977afff +_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <E8B35F18-1B5A-3C9E-B1F4-0BE0432459A2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10988a000 -        0x109893ff7 +_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <7B684803-C0A8-34D7-81CE-7A4EE7DEA614> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1098a0000 -        0x1098a4fff +math.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <C780CA87-2A8D-342E-930E-7EDBB84B3896> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x1098ab000 -        0x1098aefff +select.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <473A1E84-EAC7-30DD-A0C0-111ECA9BC60A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10993d000 -        0x10994aff7 +_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <D1740549-C698-31F9-95C7-88A38F5385F5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10995b000 -        0x1099b3ff7 +libssl.1.1.dylib (0) <1DF55B16-0F3A-3620-A4C8-6CEDF39B9620> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
       0x1099dc000 -        0x109bf21df +libcrypto.1.1.dylib (0) <34708DE8-CBA8-3112-91FA-3333E07F30DB> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
       0x109cc2000 -        0x109cc6fff +_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <2379780F-4AB4-394B-B5AB-55A517D6627E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109ccf000 -        0x109cd2ff7 +binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <58A5F4AD-285A-35E3-90C4-08A3D3D14BF2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109d56000 -        0x109d58ff7 +_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <A6066959-BCC0-3790-9FB2-8B8A9ECBF097> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109d5d000 -        0x109d62ff7 +_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <5D4A9B1B-FE9F-34EA-BD75-7B3CDDBB7CD0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109d67000 -        0x109d77ff7 +_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <E32B9196-5FD3-38FF-BF4E-EF74519A0AFA> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109d7d000 -        0x109d7dff7 +_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <A4FCF31A-2AA6-3EAC-AF46-2F2D10EC1AB1> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109d80000 -        0x109d81ff7 +_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <7E1DAB2E-F4F2-3DDD-BD85-C74BC8983933> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109dc5000 -        0x109dd3ff7 +_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <C1603837-F8C7-3FFF-8C6B-D527535D7535> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109e5f000 -        0x109e60ff7 +_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <B9D80A7C-A744-3A24-AA10-1CEF3CFFD022> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_queue.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109eb5000 -        0x109fb2fff +unicodedata.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <B4AE629C-6564-3E2E-9A6E-AE586EE0AD79> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x109ff8000 -        0x10a0d5fff +_brotli.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <FE870EC2-3BBF-3BE0-9499-2E527750E6A9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_brotli.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a0e4000 -        0x10a0e7ff7 +zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <993EF100-1498-3D6A-91FD-79558CAC8F13> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a2f7000 -        0x10a2f7ff7 +_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <11A650B3-FF7B-3DF1-81E2-A906553221C9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a44b000 -        0x10a44cff7 +_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <11920A4C-3AD4-3C87-95E5-418D30950610> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a450000 -        0x10a460fff +_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <B0740DFD-2C92-3A81-9E85-B7CAA9F7EF67> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a4b1000 -        0x10a4b2ff7 +_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <F89816AF-0BA9-3228-BAE7-54BA0D68EF67> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a4b6000 -        0x10a4e6ff7 +_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <AEA78736-809A-3F3E-A2A3-BDA83B0ECBA8> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a4f0000 -        0x10a4f0fff +grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <CF2821DC-6D7D-36C4-9F67-5D20E43D70B2> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a5c7000 -        0x10a5c8ff3 +_constant_time.abi3.so (0) <96047CA2-343F-3C1A-A7FC-D5E1A0B3EB93> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.abi3.so
       0x10a5cb000 -        0x10a5e5ff7 +_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <34A2EC26-072B-399C-9841-6AE90C845EA6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10a5fc000 -        0x10a5fcff7 +_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <1C12C693-374D-3CDA-8235-D20E4F60F2D7> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_scproxy.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10ae80000 -        0x10b0b39ab +_openssl.abi3.so (0) <64E0B359-C39F-3CCC-AE07-27BA9BFAEA82> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so
       0x10b3a3000 -        0x10b3a8fff +_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <58573D55-4505-383C-89CE-7B16ED7981AD> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b6a7000 -        0x10b6aefff +_elementtree.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <BCBD7BDA-D6E4-3986-AE4F-BABD7C9F1B29> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_elementtree.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b6b8000 -        0x10b6e1ff7 +pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <DFD21217-38D1-329A-844A-67778791E921> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b7c7000 -        0x10b7c7fff +_uuid.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <4283C23E-E755-3642-9450-F25DED17AE4D> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_uuid.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b7ca000 -        0x10b7cdfff +_csv.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <F629A3FE-5724-37C1-8940-6E5C172BFD77> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_csv.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b813000 -        0x10b826ff7 +_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <9C74285E-75A9-33BD-8836-AE129AFA3A86> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10b832000 -        0x10b837ff7 +array.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) <7934FE3A-C258-3F4F-AD15-47D5BE9FCE15> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/array.cpython-37m-darwin.so
       0x10e1b6000 -        0x10e246cb7  dyld (733.8) <EEA931D0-403E-3BC8-862A-CBA037DE4A74> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff29b07000 -     0x7fff29b07fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <EEBE6680-1AAB-3192-AA7C-450537B07F27> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff29b1f000 -     0x7fff2a18afef  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2) <2BDE5231-B5ED-313E-918A-876ACE1C0FCF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff2a18b000 -     0x7fff2a3f4fff  libBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <94F6B3C0-5039-3F66-8B2E-98791287E459> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2a3f5000 -     0x7fff2a6e4ff7  libBNNS.dylib (144.40.3) <F15D7D9E-0B9F-34FF-B144-DCA264614C54> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fff2a6e6000 -     0x7fff2aa8bfff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303.60.1) <DCC36295-FF39-35A1-8DF1-1E8A714E2265> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff2aa8c000 -     0x7fff2aaa1ff8  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303.60.1) <E3C0CC64-906B-3B44-B8AA-3075BA20E161> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff2aaa2000 -     0x7fff2aaa7ff3  libQuadrature.dylib (7) <17EC31E3-3D77-3B5A-8ADD-6A3DBC1531E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fff2aaa8000 -     0x7fff2ab18fff  libSparse.dylib (103) <350DAE1C-C990-343F-A98A-1B4317EAA869> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparse.dylib
    0x7fff2ab19000 -     0x7fff2ab2bfef  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1303.60.1) <8C0C7291-AC3A-3808-9D45-E359A5E03F0E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff2ab2c000 -     0x7fff2ad05ffb  libvDSP.dylib (735.40.1) <BD49856D-39CE-397F-A069-63B2F0D79529> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff2ad06000 -     0x7fff2adc1fd7  libvMisc.dylib (735.40.1) <9C40AC77-59A4-3180-AA4F-8F13CABF02D9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff2adc2000 -     0x7fff2adc2fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.11 - vecLib 3.11) <A8B35A80-7217-38B1-8A20-E8B4F73124F0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff2c4fd000 -     0x7fff2c889ff6  com.apple.CFNetwork (1121.1.2 - 1121.1.2) <CD7AA80C-C73B-39C7-AE03-A36BFB936F29> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff2dd5e000 -     0x7fff2e1defe7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1674.103) <D1F93A5F-5FB9-3088-BC16-36DBF58144C0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff2f14e000 -     0x7fff2f14efff  com.apple.CoreServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <DD05556D-DEF3-348D-878D-CA3AB5C91D66> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff2f14f000 -     0x7fff2f1d4fff  com.apple.AE (838 - 838) <1D2A4944-20FA-372A-B8DE-01067521CF8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff2f1d5000 -     0x7fff2f4b6ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1217 - 1217) <17EE58A1-232F-3E35-AC81-C88509A1CE8F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff2f4b7000 -     0x7fff2f504ffd  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 323.3) <631AEDD4-9328-33A7-ACE5-5FDE790FE7FD> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff2f505000 -     0x7fff2f50dfff  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1268.60.1 - 1268.60.1) <9C5A3C2D-CA76-329E-B80C-9CA1A1B1BE51> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff2f50e000 -     0x7fff2f747ff0  com.apple.LaunchServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <7D9167B7-8C60-3F42-BA15-8A85E6238FD2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff2f748000 -     0x7fff2f7e0ff9  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 2075.4) <E57FA2CF-3BD5-3947-84CC-976F192C07C7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff2f7e1000 -     0x7fff2f80eff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (1069.11 - 1069.11) <C7F894DA-EA68-3467-B004-1D6C7D58703A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff2f80f000 -     0x7fff2f876fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.1 - 1.4.1) <644BE782-F3CA-3CC2-A062-5472ECC68230> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff2f877000 -     0x7fff2f89bff5  com.apple.coreservices.SharedFileList (131.3 - 131.3) <3B586025-C347-38CF-B89F-9942CB88AA79> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SharedFileList.framework/Versions/A/SharedFileList
    0x7fff300eb000 -     0x7fff300f1fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.7 - 2.7) <8B55B221-DB4E-3CCD-B104-FC52A4127A66> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff30423000 -     0x7fff307ebff4  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1674.103) <9D7DB588-6BDC-3D7B-B267-761D4ECC88A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff30b62000 -     0x7fff30c05ffb  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1726.60.2) <65BD2F00-4BC5-3EF6-BF4D-DA1F0513E2B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff34470000 -     0x7fff3447cffe  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <C803F10A-5C01-365B-A988-64B021DCDDD5> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff37042000 -     0x7fff3705efff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.15 - 220.40.1) <BD6064BC-F588-3A34-A70C-CF8B62CA04E0>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python crashing on MacOS 10.15 Beta (19A582a) with "/usr/lib/libcrypto.dylib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58272830/python-crashing-on-macos-10-15-beta-19a582a-with-usr-lib-libcrypto-dylib)

Answer (score 6):

Your python is pointing to an unversioned libcrypto dylib. This is not allowed anymore. If re-installing python with home-brew doesn't help you can try this which worked for me (found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119429):

In 1), run brew commands sequentially:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl
```

In 2), change dir not only to /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t, but to the lib subdir

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib
```

In 3), change dir to the /usr/local/lib before making the softlinks, so they are created in the /usr/local/lib

```
cd /usr/local/lib
```

In 3) back up the current links, such to be safe

```
mv libssl.dylib libssl_bak.dylib
mv libcrypto.dylib libcrypto_bak.dylib
```

So overall, the steps were:

```
brew update && brew upgrade && brew install openssl
cd /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib
sudo cp libssl.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/
cd /usr/local/lib
mv libssl.dylib libssl_bak.dylib
mv libcrypto.dylib libcrypto_bak.dylib
sudo ln -s libssl.1.0.0.dylib libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.dylib
```

Comment: cd: no such file or directory: /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t/lib

Comment: Do you have home brew?

Comment: Remember that when you update the openssl, it may not be the same version as listed. Current stable version is 1.1.1. So, the path will become `/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib`

Comment: This is actually way easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58445755/1590134

Comment: My problem was solved by this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168647/multiprocessing-causes-python-to-crash-and-gives-an-error-may-have-been-in-progr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168647/multiprocessing-causes-python-to-crash-and-gives-an-error-may-have-been-in-progr)

Answer (score 4):

Works for me, but the solution was easier:
*Remark: openssl version can be different*

`brew install openssl
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libssl.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libcrypto.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib`