# Python get segmentation fault after update macos to 10.15.5

Tags: python-3.x, macos, macos-catalina

I use python3.8.3 for work and after update MAC OS X to 10.15.5 python3 crushed with a segfault

I tried to update OpenSSL [macOS Catalina: Python Quit unexpectedly error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888499/macos-catalina-python-quit-unexpectedly-error) but it didn't help

See error below

```
Process:               Python [27175]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.8.3 (3.8.3)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [24697]
Responsible:           pycharm [8636]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-06-01 13:42:23.958 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.5 (19F96)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.5 (17P5290)
Anonymous UUID:        5797C183-EB8E-7120-EC7D-EC0F2C1BF8E7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       986C6236-FC1E-46A9-BFBC-76EA8B17CB65

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       32000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [27175]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010b324000-000000010b325000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff6cde3e52 _platform_strlen + 18
1   etree.cpython-38-darwin.so      0x000000010c2d3e9f __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_funicode + 15
2   etree.cpython-38-darwin.so      0x000000010c392c03 __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree_8iterwalk__start_node + 195
3   etree.cpython-38-darwin.so      0x000000010c390f00 __pyx_pw_4lxml_5etree_8iterwalk_5__next__ + 1856
4   etree.cpython-38-darwin.so      0x000000010c2fdcc1 __pyx_f_4lxml_5etree__tree_to_target + 3537
5   etree.cpython-38-darwin.so      0x000000010c3d5445 __pyx_pw_4lxml_5etree_33tostring + 4229
6   org.python.python               0x000000010b351565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
7   org.python.python               0x000000010b41fca5 call_function + 533
8   org.python.python               0x000000010b41cbd8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25976
9   org.python.python               0x000000010b420a94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
10  org.python.python               0x000000010b35204e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
11  org.python.python               0x000000010b41fc4c call_function + 444
12  org.python.python               0x000000010b41cb45 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25829
13  org.python.python               0x000000010b420a94 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
14  org.python.python               0x000000010b35204e _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 270
15  org.python.python               0x000000010b41fc4c call_function + 444
16  org.python.python               0x000000010b41cbd8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25976
17  org.python.python               0x000000010b36222e gen_send_ex + 206
18  _asyncio.cpython-38-darwin.so   0x000000010baa7ed1 task_step + 865
19  _asyncio.cpython-38-darwin.so   0x000000010baa7aee TaskWakeupMethWrapper_call + 430
20  org.python.python               0x000000010b351565 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
21  org.python.python               0x000000010b43c7cd context_run + 253
22  org.python.python               0x000000010b38df64 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 132
.......
```