# Pyspark UDF function is throwing an error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve the difference between two timestamp column values. Trying to achieve the same result using different methods available in spark. I am able to achieve the same result using Spark SQL and a normal function. But, when I am trying to register this function as UDF, it starts throwing an error.

***Data:***

```
id|end_date|start_date|location
1|2015-10-14 00:00:00|2015-09-14 00:00:00|CA-SF
2|2015-10-15 01:00:20|2015-08-14 00:00:00|CA-SD
3|2015-10-16 02:30:00|2015-01-14 00:00:00|NY-NY
4|2015-10-17 03:00:20|2015-02-14 00:00:00|NY-NY
5|2015-10-18 04:30:00|2014-04-14 00:00:00|CA-SD
```

***Using SparkSQL: Works Fine !!***

```
data.createOrReplaceTempView("data_tbl")
query = "SELECT id, end_date, start_date,\
        datediff(end_date,start_date) as dtdiff FROM data_tbl"

spark.sql(query).show()
```

***Using Python Function: Works Fine !!***

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff

def get_diff(x, y):
    result = datediff(x,y)
    return result

data.withColumn('differ',get_diff('end_date','start_date')).show()
```

***result in both cases :***

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------+------+
| id|           end_date|         start_date|location|differ|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------+------+
|  1|2015-10-14 00:00:00|2015-09-14 00:00:00|   CA-SF|    30|
|  2|2015-10-15 01:00:20|2015-08-14 00:00:00|   CA-SD|    62|
|  3|2015-10-16 02:30:00|2015-01-14 00:00:00|   NY-NY|   275|
|  4|2015-10-17 03:00:20|2015-02-14 00:00:00|   NY-NY|   245|
|  5|2015-10-18 04:30:00|2014-04-14 00:00:00|   CA-SD|   552|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+--------+------+
```

***Register function as UDF: Not Working !!***

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, datediff
get_diff_udf = udf(lambda x, y: datediff(x,y))
data.withColumn('differ',get_diff_udf('end_date','start_date')).show()
```

***Error:***

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o934.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 18.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 18.0 (TID 18, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

Comment: using Spark Dataframe API functions inside a UDF is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable fork safety by setting the `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY` environment variable to `YES`. This has solved the same issue for me.

You can include this in your script:

```
import os
os.environ['OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY'] = 'YES'
```

To know more about `fork safety` or why we need to set that env variable:

[Multiprocessing causes Python to crash and gives an error may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168647/multiprocessing-causes-python-to-crash-and-gives-an-error-may-have-been-in-progr)

Comment: Nice nontrivial fix, can you summarize quickly what is *fork safety* ?

Comment: @EnzoBnl `Fork safety` is added security basically restricting multithreading.