# GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator "Task exited with return code -6"

Tags: airflow

I am new to airflow and I am trying something simple with GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator:

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'schedule_interval': None,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'params': {
        'work_dir': '/tmp'
    }
}

dag = DAG(
    'foo',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='This is foobar',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(weeks=1),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60))

mock_download = GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator(
    task_id='download-foo-from-gcp',
    bucket='foo-data',
    object='{% if (task_instance.pid % 2 == 0) %}foo{% else %}bar{% endif %}/data.tar.gz',
    filename='{{ params.work_dir }}/data.tar.gz',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    dag=dag
)
```

While I can run this task in PyCharm for example (using `airflow test`), it fails all the time when triggered from the web interface (scheduled). The error message in the log is completely useless, to say the least:

```
... 
[2020-01-09 17:04:18,871] {gcs_download_operator.py:86} INFO - Executing download: crunchbase-mock-data, foo/data.tar.gz, /tmp/data.tar.gz
[2020-01-09 17:04:28,751] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-01-09 17:04:28,751] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code -6
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? What the heck is -6 supposed to mean? Is there a way to see a little more details about what happened there?

Comment: Can you change the logging level to DEBUG and share those logs please and I will help you identify on what might be going wrong

Comment: Also please let me know what version of Airflow are you using and your environment (e.g Are you using managed Airflow services: Astronomer, Cloud Composer or running it on VMs, in which case which Linux distro)

Comment: And what Executor and DB Backend do you use ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue in [Airflow task running tweepy exits with return code -6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821777/airflow-task-running-tweepy-exits-with-return-code-6).

Are you on Mac OS High Sierra (or above)? If so, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230415/4434664. It solved my issue.

Basically, `airflow test`/`PyCharm` merely runs the task in-process, but the scheduler would start a worker process which would call `fork()`, and apparently, High Sierra introduced some new security changes that's breaking `fork()` usages in python.

This also caused problems in ansible. Refer https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/32499#issuecomment-341578864

Comment: You just earned yourself 50 points. Well done! And thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Can anyone shed any light on this? What the heck is -6 supposed to mean?*

[There is](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) a contract that

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal
>   N (POSIX only).

In your case it means that the process was terminated by SIGABRT (code 6) signal

*Is there a way to see a little more details about what happened there?*

There is no much background info from your site. In general, try to play with different operators and files.
Also, from my perspective Airflow is not well documented. And I recommend to check Airflow sources.

Comment: What baffles me somewhat is that the code works to a degree. It runs fine on Composer but fails to run locally. With identical configuration. Can I get you any more info to analyse this problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention another piece of information: when I execute the task using `airflow test`, it runs fine. When running it via scheduler, I get that -6 signal problem. What gives?