# Why is my simple HttpOperator making my local airflow scheduler crash?

Tags: https, airflow

I installed airflow on my macOS, running as standalone with sqlite db, Im just doing simple testing.
I could run bashoperators successfully, but for some reason, everytime I try this HttpOperator, my scheduler crashes. I delete all airflow processes and restart with "airflow standalone" but same behavior repeats. I have no clue on how to solve this.
Is it really because of the limits of the Sqlite/SequentialExecutor, there is no way right ? Could be https operator related ?

endpoint is valid : https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts

connection correctly set : test_api http        https://gorest.co.in/public/v2      False   False

apache-airflow==2.5.1

Thank you for your help

```
PycharmProjects/composer/logs/dag_id=test_api/run_id=scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00/task_id=is_api_active/attempt=4.log
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1083} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_api.is_api_active scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1083} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_api.is_api_active scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1279} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1280} INFO - Starting attempt 4 of 4
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1281} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1300} INFO - Executing <Task(HttpSensor): is_api_active> on 2024-01-30 09:00:00+00:00
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 44845 to run task
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_api', 'is_api_active', 'scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '29', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_api.py', '--cfg-path', '/var/folders/84/5q_1yj555494bdjdy7m78pv40000gp/T/tmp6pg6_8t6']
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 29: Subtask is_api_active
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {task_command.py:388} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_api.is_api_active scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host pc-156.home
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1507} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=xxxxxx
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_api
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=is_api_active
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=4
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2024-01-30T09:00:00+00:00
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {http.py:122} INFO - Poking: posts/
[2024-01-31, 11:40:28 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'test_api' for task execution.
```

Dag code:

```
import json

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['Benoit.FAGOT.ext@ag2rlamondiale.fr'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'retries': 0,
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
    # 'wait_for_downstream': False,
    # 'dag': dag,
    # 'sla': timedelta(hours=2),
    # 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300),
    # 'on_failure_callback': some_function,
    # 'on_success_callback': some_other_function,
    # 'on_retry_callback': another_function,
    # 'sla_miss_callback': yet_another_function,
    # 'trigger_rule': 'all_success'
}

with DAG(
    'test_api',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval="0 9 * * *",
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['example'],

) as dag:

    def debug(response):
        print(response)
        if "200" in response:
            return True
        return False

    task_is_api_active = HttpSensor(
        task_id="is_api_active",
        http_conn_id='test_api',
        endpoint='posts/'
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

a few things I see that need to be corrected:

1. The http connection_id test_api does not end with a / . So your request will go to ...v2posts/ instead of v2/posts
2. If your endpoint is https please add

   extra_options = {'verify':False},
3. you can also use response_check=debug in the HttpSensor call to check the response, HttpSensor by default runs repeatedly with an interval of 60 seconds unless the response check returns true.
4. Before you make this DAG as scheduled I suggest to try with scheduled_interval=None and see if it runs or not
5. I was able to run this snippet below with https://gorest.co.in/ in the connection_id Host

```html
import json

from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
}

with DAG(
    'test_api',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    catchup=False,

) as dag:

    def debug(response):
        print(response)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return True
        return False

    task_is_api_active = HttpSensor(
        task_id="is_api_active",
        http_conn_id='so_test_api',
        endpoint='public/v2/posts',
        extra_options = {'verify':False},
        response_check=debug
    )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, I adapted my code to run your snippet but it still isnt working (also switched to a postgresql db / LocalExecutor), the task just goes forever " Poking: public/v2/posts"

My next guess is thats I have some kind of firewall blocking my apicalls (work computer), because i dont see why the code woudnt work, its so basic :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying to call the API with a pythonOperator, and having the same problem, I boiled it down to it being an issue with my computer

this answer confirmed it, as I got my PythonOperator to work with this "no_proxy=*" line... [Airflow - External API call gives Negsignal.SIGSEGV error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582293/airflow-external-api-call-gives-negsignal-sigsegv-error)

seems like a macOS bug https://bugs.python.org/issue28342