# How to lookup an amazon.aws.aws_secret in ansible-playbook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am looking for a way to lookup a secret stored in Amazon AWS secrets manager. I am following the the official documentation in [this link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html).

The test playbook I used is:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Lookup secret
      debug:
        msg: "{{ query('amazon.aws.aws_secret', 'my_secret', region='us-west-1') }} "
```

but I got the error:

```
TASK [Lookup secret] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
objc[22931]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[22931]: +[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state
```

Has anyone successfully looked up an amazon.aws.aws_secret in ansible?

Here is my ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.2
...
  python version = 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:07:53) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was encountered in ansible, but it turns out to be a generic Python and MacOS issue. The example in the question worked after setting:

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

per a post in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168647/multiprocessing-causes-python-to-crash-and-gives-an-error-may-have-been-in-progr).