# Fork() crashes Python in Mac OS Monterey

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm running Djangorq on my virtualenv with python 3.8.6 as follows

```
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES;sudo python manage.py rqworker --with-scheduler
```

When I call any function as

```
django_rq.enqueue(func, request.user,arg=arg1)
```

Python crashes and I get this on my console:

> +[NSPlaceholderString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
> objc[78776]: +[NSPlaceholderString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
> 12:33:17 Moving job to FailedJobRegistry (work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 6)

Before Monterey, I used to solve it with
`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`
But this doesn't seem to work anymore.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try `export no_proxy=*`

Comment: More context why you think this is the right solution?

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/72575205/3066788
2) https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/issues/9007#issuecomment-381795518
3) https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/74570#issuecomment-1093748531
4) https://bugs.python.org/msg329926

Comment: Running via `no_proxy='*' OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES python ...` fixed the issue for me. It also worked if I set those env vars in the Python script via `os.environ`, before forking.

Comment: Another solution which worked for me is to cache proxy initialization in the main process, as described at https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2761