# Error using searchkick (ElasticSearch) on Rails (macOS 12.4) ETHON: Libcurl initialized objc[36397]: +[NSNumber initialize]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Trying to use searchkick (ElasticSearch) on macOS Monterey 12.4 in the local console (i.e. `Model.reindex`) results in the following error:

```
ETHON: Libcurl initialized
objc[36397]: +[NSNumber initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[36397]: +[NSNumber initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52230415/1276696

Add the following line to your `.bash_profile` and restart your terminal:

`export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY="YES"`

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful debugging some libcurl macos issues (curb gem)