# Python - Gunicorn crashes on GPU inference

Tags: python, flask, gpu, gunicorn, onnxruntime

I'm creating a local API for macOS that process inferences on a ONNX model (MiDaS) in python. I use `onnxruntime-silicon` (a fork of `onnxruntime`) to run the model on Apple Silicon GPU and `Flask` for the server side. I manage to get my script working with Flask development server but I can't make Gunicorn work on this task.

### Using Flask development server (working)

Here is a working python3 script (using deployment server):

```py
# Server libraries
from flask import Flask
# NN and Image processing libraries
import onnxruntime as ort
from cv2 import imread, imwrite, cvtColor, COLOR_BGR2RGB
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

# Use a GPU provider if available
providers = ort.get_available_providers()

# Load ONNX model
sess = ort.InferenceSession("models/model-f6b98070.onnx", providers=providers)

def postprocess(depth_map):

    '''Process and save the depth map as a JPG'''

    # Rescale to 0-255, convert to uint8 and save the image
    rescaled = (255.0 / depth_map[0].max() * (depth_map[0] - depth_map[0].min())).astype(np.uint8)
    rescaled = np.squeeze(rescaled)
    imwrite('tmp/depth.jpg', rescaled)

def preprocess(image='tmp/frame.jpg'):

    '''Load and process the image for the model'''

    input_image = imread(image) # Load image with OpenCV (384x384 only!)
    input_image = cvtColor(input_image, COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Convert to RGB
    input_array = np.transpose(input_image, (2,0,1)) # Reshape (H,W,C) to (C,H,W)
    input_array = np.expand_dims(input_array, 0) # Add the batch dimension B
    normalized_input_array = input_array.astype('float32') / 255 # Normalize
    return normalized_input_array

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    # Load input image
    input_array = preprocess()
    # Process inference
    input_name = sess.get_inputs()[0].name
    results = sess.run(None, {input_name: input_array})
    # Save depth map
    postprocess(results)
    return 'DONE'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I can make a request like so:

```py
import requests
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict')
print(response.status_code)
```

The depth map is saved as JPG, everything works as expected.

### Using Gunicorn server (not working)

Now if I want to switch from the default `Flask` server (made for development) to `Gunicorn` (production WSGI server). Starting from the first script, I import the following libraries:

```py
from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication
import gunicorn.glogging
import gunicorn.workers.sync
```

I create a Gunicorn class:

```py
class GunicornApplication(BaseApplication):
    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.application = app
        self.options = options or {}
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        for key, value in self.options.items():
            if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None:
                self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application
```

And initialize the script like so:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = {'bind': '127.0.0.1:5000', 'workers': 1}
    GunicornApplication(app, options).run()
```

The server launch without issue but python crash when I make a request for inferences, and the script raise the following error:

```py
>>> [ERROR] Worker (pid:10517) was sent SIGSEGV!
```

I get the following exeption from my request:

```py
>>> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I know the error is cause by GPU since the `Gunicorn` script works well if the provider is set on CPU. Maybe the issue is link to a bad communication between the script and Gunicorn server threads?

Any help or suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, each worker needs to load the model in its own memory block, so I decided to properly load the model for each worker with a `load_model` fonction and the Gunicorn `post_worker_init` parameter:

```py
sess = None

def load_model(_):
    global sess
    providers = ort.get_available_providers()
    sess = ort.InferenceSession("/opt/FCPX Studio/Utils/depth map/models/model-f6b98070.onnx", providers=providers)

class GunicornApplication(BaseApplication):

    [...]

    def load_config(self):
        for key, value in self.options.items():
            if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None:
                self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

        # Set up the post_worker_init hook to load the model.
        self.cfg.set('post_worker_init', load_model)

    [...]
```

This didn't fix the issue but allowed me to receive the following error from the server on the inference requests:

```
objc[51435]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

The fork safety block the process and crash python. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73738232/14253533) as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424472/issues-with-python-threading-flask-and-gunicorn) explain quit well the issue. I'm still not quit sure what exactly caused the fork safety to block the process.

In the meantime I can disable the fork safety with an environment variable like so:

```bash
export OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```