# WSGI container in flask

Tags: multithreading, flask, wsgi, gevent

What is point of communication if i run flask application with wsgi container  (WSGI container gevent + flask application) and what is difference if i use this solution and if i run just flask applciation with app.run(Threaded=True) command.

If i understand correctly in first case..... web browser=>wsgi=>application

(five users,five threads from web browsers to WSGI => one thread from wsgi to application)

and in second case ... (web browser=> application) without WSGI container every user is one thread...

Can someone explain me if i mean it right and whats point of using WSGI ? Google did not give me answer...

Comment: WSGI containers give you flexibility and scalability through a separation of concerns. They make it easier to juggle app worker processes, threads and connections, e.g.; http://stackoverflow.com/a/35839360/6085135

Comment: Suggest you go read this series of posts to learn about how Python web servers work and how WSGI interface for applications works. https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/