# Handling multiple requests in PyMC3 Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing, pymc3

I have a flask application that calls Bayesian models written in PyMC3. Whenever more than one request is made simultaneously, the application processes each request separately keeping the other ones in queue.

I have tried using 'threaded=True' and running through a Gunicorn server with gevent asynchronous workers as mentioned in 
[How to run Flask with Gunicorn in multithreaded mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837786/how-to-run-flask-with-gunicorn-in-multithreaded-mode) , but still the issue persists.

Is this a specific issue related to pyMC3?